# Does the HP LPE12002 support PXE booting?

Tags: hp, pxe-boot

The card is labeled as a LPe12002 (specifically this one www.avagotech.com/products/server-storage/fibre-channel-host-bus-adapters/lpe12002). The card is in a Gen9 HP. When I go into the BIOS I do not see the card listed, knowing that you have to enable it on Intel x520 cards via firmware I looked all over the documentation and never found any documentation stating it actually supports PXE booting.

The feature page says

> Deployment and Management Features:
>
> Universal boot capability allows the appropriate boot environment to be automatically selected for any given hardware.
>
> Boot-from-SAN capability reduces system management costs and increases uptime.
>
> Detailed real-time event logging and tracing enables quick diagnosis of SAN problems.
>
> Beaconing feature flashes the HBA LEDs, simplifying their identification within server racks.
>
> Environmental monitoring feature helps to optimize SAN availability.

It never mentions PXE booting. Digging into the documentation, I never saw any information regarding the capability to boot from PXE.

I would expect it, but I can't see any reference to it or how to enable it. Does anyone know?

http://www.avagotech.com/products/server-storage/fibre-channel-host-bus-adapters/lpe12002#documentation

Comment: Unless I'm completely missing something here, you're confusing two very different things.  PXE = booting off network, using a network adapter.  This is a card that presents storage over a network as local.  It does not present a network adapter. If this is some sort of converged network / SAN hybrid that does present a network adapter, I'm not seeing it mentioned in the product info.  This card will let you boot from storage on a remote SAN, not PXE boot.  What does PXE boot mean to you?

Comment: @yoonix Ahhh, okay that makes more sense with the information that I was reading on the card. I had asked for 10Gb fiber based network cards (e.g. Intel X520). This is what I got in the server, but when asked they said yeah, that is it. So I wasn't sure if it was something I was missing or not. If you want to write this as an answer or write "OP is an idiot" I'll be glad to accept it :).